# React app + compiled libraries > require not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, drupal

I'm using compiled libraries to create a React app on my Drupal.

```
    https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js: { external: true, minified: true }
    https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js: { external: true, minified: true }
    https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js: { external: true, minified: true }
```

In a custom code, I have defined a file (app.js) and I can see that the react app work perfectly.

Example code :

```
class App extends React.Component {

// Define default values.
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // Setting up initial state
  this.state = {
    data: []
  }
}

// Call the componentDidMount().
componentDidMount() {

// Here I build a code to create a value to render.

}

render() {
  // Here I call the element to render...
    })
  return (
  .....
```

But, I have a problem if I want to call an external component. If I add an import at the beginning of my app.js I get an error :

```
// import { mycomponent } from './mycomponent.js';
// import mycomponent from './mycomponent';
// const { mycomponent } from './mycomponent';
// ....

error: .... require not defined
```

To call my component, I'm trying to use import or const without success.

I don't use node.js (or browserify...) on this project, only the above compiled libraries. After reading many many posts, I don't see how to procced to import/call my component.

Can I call an external component without these default React elements : node.js... ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the other details of your setup, but to use `import` you need to compile your code into ES2015 code. The babel plugin is *@babel/polyfill*: You can read more [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#docsNav)